# joining three tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables. table A has two fields code and item. Table B has 3 fields code, qty_recd and recd_dt. Table C has 3 fields Code, qty_sold, sold_dt. I want to get a result in this way:

For each record in Table A, sum of qty_recd from Table B and sum of qty_sold from Table C.

```
TABLE-A

code      Item
-----     ------
A1       AMMONIA SOLUTION


TABLE-B

code     qty_recd       recd_dt
-----    --------       -------
A1         5            2013-06-01
A1         8            2013-04-18
A1         3            2013-05-22


TABLE-C

code     qty_sold       sold_dt
-----    --------       -------
A1         1            2013-08-10
A1         4            2013-09-01
A1         2            2013-05-11
```

I want result like this

```
code      item            tot_recd       tot_sold
-----    --------         -------       --------
A1     AMMONIA SOLUTION     16             6
```

I tried several constructs, but not getting desired output. Please help to construct SELECT statement

Comment: Can you post some of the things you tried? (You can edit the question to add them, don't try to squeeze them into comments.) It seems you know that `JOIN` is the key word here, so maybe we can fill in a gap in your understanding of how that works?

Comment: Please show your SELECT statements & results. This will stop down votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to join your master product list to two summaries.  (Don't use hyphens in table names routinely!)

One of the summaries is:

```
   SELECT code, SUM(qty_recd) AS qty_recd
     FROM `TABLE-B`
    GROUP BY code
```

You can guess the other.

Your overall query should be

```
   SELECT a.code, a.item, b.qty_recd, c.qty_sold
     FROM `TABLE-A` AS a
     LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT code, SUM(qty_recd) AS qty_recd
           FROM `TABLE-B`
          GROUP BY code
     ) AS b ON a.code = b.code
     LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT code, SUM(qty_sold) AS qty_sold
           FROM `TABLE-C`
          GROUP BY code
     ) AS c ON a.code = c.code
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle showing it.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cb7/1/0

You might naively just JOIN all three tables and then use GROUP BY.  But then you'd be summarizing this nasty cross-product derived table:

```
CODE      qty_recd    qty_sold
A1         5              1
A1         5              4
A1         5              2
A1         8              1
A1         8              4
A1         8              2
A1         3              1
A1         3              4
A1         3              2
```

For example, this **incorrect** query would do that.

```
      SELECT a.code, a.item, SUM(b.qty_recd), SUM(c.qty_sold) //WRONG!
        FROM `TABLE-A` AS a
   LEFT JOIN `TABLE-B` AS b ON a.code = b.code
   LEFT JOIN `TABLE-C` AS C ON a.code = c.code
    GROUP BY a.code, a.item
```

See this fiddle.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cb7/3/0

That's not what you want.  Hence the need for summary subqueries.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no need for sub-queries here, they just complicate the query.

Comment: As all the tables have a common field, wouldn't a simple join be more efficient than subqueries on each table?

Comment: A three way unsummarized join will yield lots of extra rows when there's more than one item for each code in either table-b or table-c.

Comment: Ah, right, I think I get where you're coming from. You should try to explain that in the answer, though, as it may be what the OP was struggling with in the first place.

Comment: Brilliant. Until you laid out the ungrouped table like that it hadn't even occurred to me that it would be effectively a `CROSS JOIN` between the B and C tables. :)

Comment: This is fine working well... Thanks